# RegExp for parsing html;

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, facebook, parsing

Could you help me to make RegExp? In large string I need to find these substrings(2 formats):

http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100002234024152&ref=ffa\
http://www.facebook.com/alesya.yuldasheva?ref=ffa\

I tried these:

```
@"\\b(https?):\/\/www.facebook.com([.]{*})ref=ffa";
@"[{http:\/\/www.facebook.com}([.]{*}){ref=ffa}]";
@"[http:\/\/www.facebook.com]([.])*[ref=ffa]";
```

I use RegexKitLite, which syntax same as normal objective c regular expressions.

Comment: you should probably x out the name in the address as it leads directly to your, or some elses, facebook page. something  like `http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx?ref=ffa\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *htmlAdr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error){
    NSLog(@"Yaz");
}
 // NSLog(@"%@", htmlAdr);
NSString *wereWeAreGoingToFind = htmlAdr;
NSString *whatWewAreGoingToFind1 = @"\\bhttps?:\\\\/\\\\/[a-zA-Z0-9\\-.]*\\\\/profile.php\\?id=([\\d]*)\\&amp;ref=ffa";
NSString *whatWewAreGoingToFind = @"\\bhttps?:\\\\/\\\\/[a-zA-Z0-9\\-.]*\\\\/([a-zA-Z0-9\\-.]*)\\?ref=pb";
NSArray *matchArray = [wereWeAreGoingToFind componentsMatchedByRegex:whatWewAreGoingToFind capture:1L];
NSArray *matchArray1 = [wereWeAreGoingToFind componentsMatchedByRegex:whatWewAreGoingToFind1 capture:1L];
matchArray = [matchArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:matchArray1];
NSLog(@"%@", matchArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know no objective-c, but this regular expression is what you want:

[`\b(https?)://www.facebook.com/(.*?)ref=ffa\b`](http://regexr.com?2v1dk)

It goes without saying that you'll need to escape the slashes yourself

Comment: I know that you thing in right way. I tried to make exactly the same, but obj c has not usual syntax(not like perl for example)... So I know what i need to do, but don't now how..

Comment: @user997822: Looking at the documentation, the syntax looks fairly standard.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to escape the '.' in the url too. For example:

@"\b(https?)://www\.facebook\.com/(.*?)ref=ffa";